# Loose XAML is version of .NET/CLR loaded dependent on referenced namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, clr

I have just been reading WPF Unleashed and it mentioned that the button will look different depending on the XMLNS used.

So I tried the following and it and it bang on right.

In this code the glossy button is loaded.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <StackPanel Height="40">
        <Button Content="Button1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

In this code the non-glossy button is loaded.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation">
    <StackPanel Height="40">
        <Button Content="Button1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I am just trying to figure out what actually is happening?
Is it just hardcoded that the **PresentationHost.exe** loads the **4.0 CLR** when it sees the **../netfx/2009/...** namespace?

Answer (score 3):

Inside `PresentationFramework.dll` there is a mapping using the [`XmlnsDefinitionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx).

When the compiler hits the namespace, it looks for the specified dlls matching the target XAML namespace:

```
[System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06", "System.Windows.Media.Animation"),
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxationsAttribute(8)
```

If it hits `winfx/2006` it will look for the XAML 2006 corresponding dlls. If it hits `netfx/2009` it will look for the XAML 2009 dlls.

Comment: The v4.0 Assemblies contain the 2006,2007 & 2009 XmlnsDefinitionAttribute.
The v3.0 only contains the 2006,2007.

My question is actually related how PresentationHost detects which version of the PresentationFramework.dll it should load.

I assume it checks oldest -> newest DLL's, because when referencing the 2006 xmlns it still loads the v2.0 instead of v4.0.